# using io.SectionReader and error handling clutter

Tags: go, stream

I am writing something that takes a file and reads the header (first 48 bytes) of a file (our own silly format from 1995) which contain 6 offsets (amongst other meta data) that I then SEEK to in order to read data specific to our domain, then finally pull the last 16 bytes of the file to read the checksum (of sorts).

My code is using a io.SectionReader and is (at a simplistic level) like this:

```
const PackHeaderSize = 48
const PackFooterSize = 16
packedHeader := make([]byte, PackHeaderSize)
sr.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
sr.Read(packedHeader)

// Do some decoding of packedHeader to get the offsets into an array
// ChunkSize varies based on the PackedHeader meta data
// Data is written to a Crc32 Hash

for i := 0; i < offsets; i++ {
 chunk := make([]byte, ChunkSize)
 sr.Seek(offset, io.SeekCurrent)
 sr.Read(chunk)
 crc.Write(chunk)
}

footer := make([]byte, PackFooterSize)
sr.Read(footer)

// Compare footer CRC with the crc computed value
```

I'm still very new to go but it seems I have to check for errors in every sr.Seek and sr.Read which gives a lot of verbose code. Is there a nicer way to write the above?

I've tried to put them into seperate functions but the code becomes very messy. The original was written in C (in 1989 or 90) and was very verbose (because they calculated a checksum by reading every byte - not CRC, something else).

How do I stream from one array, into another in a golang way or handle errors in an elegant way?